# PNG output fails in TeXworks

Tags: texmaker, texworks, png

I am using Tex Live on Windows 11.  I was finally able to produce a PNG file by executing the following TEX file from the Windows 11 command line.  If executed from the TexWorks editor it is unsuccessful (pertinent log file lines below.)

On the way to getting this to work, I had to install two additional programs: ImageMagick and Ghostscript.  Also, I have the -shell-escape option enabled in my texmf.cnf file.  Googling helped and hindered!

The ImageMagick 'convert' command has been renamed to 'magick'.  My system has a 'convert' command that wants to convert my hard drive file system!

It turned out that ImageMagick actually uses Ghostscript code, so that had to be installed.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=640x360,outext=.png,convertexe=magick}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Trying to export a PNG!
\end{document}
```

The output obtained using the command line pdflatex:

[image]

The log file using TexWorks follows.

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
> (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.20)  24 MAR 2023 10:36 entering
> extended mode  \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
> **PNG_out.tex (./PNG_out.tex LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
> Document Class: standalone 2022/10/10 v1.3b Class to compile TeX
> sub-files stan dalone
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty Package:
> shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
> Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line
> 75. ) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex
> instead.
>
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty Package: iftex
> 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests ))
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty Package:
> xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
>
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
> \XKV@toks=\toks16 \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
>
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
> \XKV@depth=\count185 File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value
> parser (HA) )) \sa@internal=\count186 \c@sapage=\count187
>
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg File:
> standalone.cfg 2022/10/10 v1.3b Default configuration file for
> 'standalon e' class )
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
> article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File: size10.clo
> 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count188
> \c@section=\count189 \c@subsection=\count190
> \c@subsubsection=\count191 \c@paragraph=\count192
> \c@subparagraph=\count193 \c@figure=\count194 \c@table=\count195
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip48 \belowcaptionskip=\skip49
> \bibindent=\dimen140 ) \sa@box=\box51 runsystem(pdflatex
> -shell-escape  -jobname 'PNG_out' '\expandafter\def\csname  sa@internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{PNG_out}')...executed.
>
> \sa@read=\read2
>
> Executing command: magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch
> PNG_out.pdf -resize 640x360 -quality 9 0 PNG_out.png
>
> runsystem(magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch PNG_out.pdf -resize
> 640x360
> -quality 90 PNG_out.png)...executed.
>
> Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful! (standalone)
> There might be something wrong with your (standalone)
> conversation software or the file permissions!
>
> ) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  845 strings out of
> 476025  14170 string characters out of 5794015  1849382 words of
> memory out of 5000000  21358 multiletter control sequences out of
> 15000+600000  512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000
> for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  57i,1n,71p,202b,60s
> stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
>
> No pages of output. PDF statistics:  0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max.
> 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of
> extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
>
> TeX's memory you used:  1039 strings out of 476025  19587 string
> characters out of 5794015  1849382 words of memory out of 5000000
> 21542 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  512287 words
> of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation
> exceptions out of 8191  61i,5n,74p,258b,102s stack positions out of
> 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
> <c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
> Output written on PNG_out.pdf (1 page, 14509 bytes). PDF statistics:
> 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  7 compressed objects within
> 1 object stream  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1
> words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

**And, here's the log file differences using pdflatex at the command prompt vs in TeXworks:**

> Comparing files PNG_out_pdflatex.log and PNG_OUT_TEXWORKS.LOG
> ***** PNG_out_pdflatex.log This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.20)  24 MAR 2023 11:40 entering extended mode
> ***** PNG_OUT_TEXWORKS.LOG This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.20)  24 MAR 2023 10:36 entering extended mode
>
> ---
>
> ***** PNG_out_pdflatex.log
>
> Class standalone: Output written on PNG_out.png.  ) )
> ***** PNG_OUT_TEXWORKS.LOG
>
> Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful! (standalone)
> There might be something wrong with your (standalone)
> conversation software or the file permissions!
>
> ) )
>
> ---
>
> ***** PNG_out_pdflatex.log
>
> Info:    ... okay on input line 2.  [1
>
> {c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
> (./PNG_out.aux)  )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  1039
> strings out of 476025
> ***** PNG_OUT_TEXWORKS.LOG
>
> TeX's memory you used:  1039 strings out of 476025
>
> ---

**Additional information 24 March 2023 at 18:00 EDT:**

I downloaded the Texmaker editor and it makes the PNG file, so I guess something strange is happening with the TeXworks editor?  Also, the log file for each working case has the "Info:    ... okay on input line 2.  [1 ..." lines in it, but the "failure" log has no such line (as shown in the differences just above).

Comment: Is imagemagick in your path?

Comment: Yes, it is in my system path.

Comment: The Windows 11 command prompt that yields the proper output: 'pdflatex PNG_out.tex'.

Comment: Can you show your .log file?

Comment: runsystem(pdflatex  -shell-escape  -jobname 'PNG_out' '\expandafter\def\csname 
sa@internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{PNG_out}')...executed.

\sa@read=\read2

Executing command:
magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch PNG_out.pdf -resize 640x360 -quality 9
0 PNG_out.png

runsystem(magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch PNG_out.pdf -resize 640x360 
-quality 90 PNG_out.png)...executed.

Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz The entire log won't fit and I haven't learned to format comments yet.  In any case, the error lines are quoted in the original question.

Comment: Can you do the conversion manually? That is, create the PDF using pdflatex or whichever engine. Then, from Windows command, invoke the `magick ...` incantation. You will probably have to modify the incantation, so specify which PDF page, if there is more than one page. If that fails: One possibility is that the helper program (Ghostscript, or whatever magick requires) is not on PATH, even though magick itself is on PATH.

Comment: @rallg:  When the .tex file is executed at the Windows command prompt using 'pdflatex PNG_out.tex', the PNG is produced.  Also, executing 'magick -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch PNG_out.pdf -resize 640x360 -quality 9 0 PNG_out.png' at the prompt works.  When executing the same tex from TeXworks,, no PNG file is produced and an "unsuccessful" error is indicated in the log.

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz:  I have edited the question to add the entire log file and the differences in the logs produced by running pdflatex at the command prompt vs from TeXworks.

Comment: Although I cannot solve your problem, you have worked a lot on your question, and narrowed it down. It does indeed sound like the problem is specific to how TeXworks interacts with other things on your system.

Comment: @rallg: Then we agree for the most part.  However, are you implying that the issue only exists on my system?   Have you been able to use the included Tex code to make a PNG file on some other system using Tex Live and TeXeditor?

Comment: @JustCurious I was able to run your code on Windows 10 2023 TeXLive 2023 TeXWorks with no issues through TeXWorks. Which platform do you use sorry?

Comment: @rallg:  I'm using Windows 11, TeX Live 2023, and newly downloaded and installed ImageMagick 7.1.1-4 Q16-HDRI x64 and GhostScript 10.01.0.,

Comment: @rallg:   I should mention that there is no indication within TeXworks that there has been a failure.  The PDF display is there, but there is no PNG file in the folder.

Comment: @JamesT:  Sorry, I responded to rallg instead of you.  So, here what I wrote.  I'm using Windows 11, TeX Live 2023, and newly downloaded and installed ImageMagick 7.1.1-4 Q16-HDRI x64 and GhostScript 10.01.0.  I should mention that there is no indication within TeXworks that there has been a failure. The PDF display is there, but there is no PNG file in the folder

Comment: My own setup is not the same (and cannot be the same) as yours, since I work in a customized system with this-and-that beyond my control. Almost anything fails for me, but it is not the fault of TeX or that software. So, ignore me. Evidently you are on top of things.

Comment: @rallg:  On top?  I feel like I'm under and sinking!  I appreciate your input.  I've tried using Ghostscript directly.  That results in a PNG file when executed in TeXworks.  However, it's not the correct width (yet).  My objective is to learn about Latex by making a picture from text that I can use to describe a photo album.  My typesetting experience is limited to using a program called RUNOFF to write a User's Manual in the 70s.